# For any real number $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ choose a positive real number $a_\lambda>0$. Show that the subset $A$ below is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis

For any real number $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ choose a positive real number $a_\lambda>0$. Then the subset $A$ below is unbounded:

$$A=\{a_{\lambda_1}+\cdots+a_{\lambda_k}\;|\; k\in\mathbb N, \lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k\in\mathbb R\}$$

What if the indices $\lambda$ were from integers but not from reals?

I dont really understand the underlying idea, if I am who is chosing then Can't I make A is bounded, trivially? Can you give me hint, and/or answer?

Comment: You are meant to consider an arbitrary collection as described.  (For the proof, consider the sets $A_n=\{ a_\lambda\,|\, a_\lambda>1/n\}$.)

Comment: Above, I should have defined  $A_n=\{ \lambda\,|\, a_\lambda>1/n\}$.